# Event for scroll [up + down] and [left + right] separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

I want to to make it so when the user scrolls up / down it goes left / right.

I am using this [jquery mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) (i'm open to others that achieve the same).

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
});
```

The `preventDefault()` is triggering for both up / down and left / right. It turns out that the functionality for up / down works great but this code makes the left / right horrible its scrolling very choppy. I would like to only `preventDefault()` for up / down.

Comment: Just a guess: `if(deltaX == 0){ event.preventDefault(); }` ?

Comment: @w4rumy this kind of works in junction with some more code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scroll Page Horizontally With Mouse Wheel](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

Add Deps:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

Add this script:

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

[Demo](https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/)